# PHP User Authentication through Email

Tags: php, security, authentication, hash, laravel

I'm working on a php/laravel-4 project, and we need to auto authenticate users coming from the  links in the emails we send them, we need to have time limit for links so a link in email would not authenticate after the expire time is passed, I've come to this approach but I have some doubts about it's security:

first I make a md5 hash using user's email, timestamp and a secret key like this:

```
$timestamp = time();
$hash = md5($email . $timestamp . $secret_key);
```

then I can generate a url like this:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/url?email={$email}&hash={$hash}&timestamp={$timestamp}
```

so then I can check the timestamp (for time validation) and regenerate the hash and authenticate the user with the provided email, do you think it has any security flaw? if yes please suggest me the secure method.

Comment: What's to prevent somebody sniffing network traffic and using this link before the intended user? It's safe to assume a lot of your users will be checking email via unencrypted methods.

Comment: why include a timestamp at all? The hash itself is theoretically unique, so send **ONLY** the hash, and store the associated user ID/timestamp in a database table. When the user clicks the link, you look up the hash in the table, check if it's still valid time-wise, and get the userID at that point.

Comment: @JohnChrysostom so what do you suggest for authenticating users through email?

Comment: @MarcB what is this risk of sending the timestamp and email? because I want to remove the database overhead.

Comment: I would suggest at least still requiring their password after they click the link. Either that or not authenticating via email...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not do that. What I would do:

Create a table for your links:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('login', function($table) {
        $table->string('id')->primary();

        $table->string('user_id');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Every time you generate a link you add a line to this table:

```
$user = User::find(1);

$login = Login::create(['id' => Login::generateID(), 'user_id' => $user->id]);

$url = "http://www.example.com/url?login_id={$login->id}"
```

Then when your user click the link you can automatically log him in, also, immediatelly invalidate that link:

```
$login = Login::findOrFail(Input::get('login_id'));

$user = User::find($login->user_id);

Auth::login($user);

$login->delete();
```

And create an Artisan Command to periodiacally delete old records on that table:

```
Login::where('created_at', '<=', Carbon\Carbon::now()->subDays(2))->delete();
```

This can be the code for `generateID()`, it's a basic UUID code generation:

```
public static function v4() 
{
    return sprintf('%04x%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x-%04x%04x%04x',

    // 32 bits for "time_low"
    mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff),

    // 16 bits for "time_mid"
    mt_rand(0, 0xffff),

    // 16 bits for "time_hi_and_version",
    // four most significant bits holds version number 4
    mt_rand(0, 0x0fff) | 0x4000,

    // 16 bits, 8 bits for "clk_seq_hi_res",
    // 8 bits for "clk_seq_low",
    // two most significant bits holds zero and one for variant DCE1.1
    mt_rand(0, 0x3fff) | 0x8000,

    // 48 bits for "node"
    mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff), mt_rand(0, 0xffff)
    );
}
```

No strings attached to anything on your system.

Comment: why not just use a random md5 hash?

Comment: You should still check the timestamp when finding the id. If for some reason there is a vulnerability in the clean up process you might get stale results. You can also run the cleanup whenever you check, or like 1/10th of the time you check.

Comment: I was not trying to give a full code implementation, just a guideline for a better way, how to really implement things it's up to the OP.  Just changed the implementation for v4, you're right about it.

Answer (score 1):

`md5` is not cryptographically safe, in the sense that it is *easy* to crack (in cryptographical terms).

The main concern is that `md5` is *fast*, you don't want that, you want it to be as slow as possible, but not so slow that it takes you too long to generate and validate.

Look at the [PHP password guide](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php), critical here is the `cost` parameter. Higher cost means it's more secure. Essentially what `cost` does is: it increases the amount of times the hash function is applied, more applications means it takes longer to produce and thus brute-force.

---

Another thing you can do is obfuscate your input. If you can change your URLs to:

```
$string = $timestamp . "|" . $email . "|" . $hash;
// then encrypt this string
$encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt($cypher, $secret_password_2, $string); // or any other two-way encryption
$url = $base . "?hash=" . $encrypted;
```

When you receive the hash decrypt it, split it and check the hash. This makes it less obvious what is going on; all 3 values are packed in one encrypted blob.

Comment: this will end up in a real long $encrypted string.

Comment: The defacto limit of URLs is 2000 characters, we're not even close! Maybe 100?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the secret key isn't the users password, then this seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find a completely secure way to do this. What if someone's email has been hacked? or a million other situations.

I think your best bet is to send an email containing a username(or email) hashed and possibly a timestamp again. Once they click the link they must enter their password then continue on their way.

You could also include a redirect link in the email link so the script can redirect them to the appropriate place after they enter a password.